# Sum two rows if two cells are the same but in different order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Similar to below

```
Buyer Seller Amount
John  Mary   3
Mary  John   2
David Bosco  2
```

Where I want to sum John and Mary rows into one

Expected out come

```
Trade1 Trade2 Amount
John   Mary   5
David  Bosco  2
```

My dataframe has around 6000 rows. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sort values by [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and create boolean mask by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df[['Buyer','Seller']] = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['Buyer','Seller']], axis=1))

df2 = df.groupby(['Buyer','Seller'], as_index=False)['Amount'].sum()
df2.columns = ['Trade1','Trade2','Amount']
print (df2)
  Trade1 Trade2  Amount
0  Bosco  David       2
1   John   Mary       5
```

If dont want modify original columns use syntactic sugar - `groupby` with `Series`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['Buyer','Seller']], axis=1))
df1.columns = ['Trade1','Trade2']

df2 = df['Amount'].groupby([df1['Trade1'],df1['Trade2']]).sum().reset_index()
print (df2)
  Trade1 Trade2  Amount
0  Bosco  David       2
1   John   Mary       5
```